# want to make user-login before view contain

Tags: users

i am making a online tutorial site where a user can view can different contain but i want then to go through login.

For example: you have a home page. after login, user get redirected to the video page. but i dont want to display video page at the homepage.

Comment: Do you want to protect the content from someone getting to it without logging in? Or just a simple redirect after login?

Answer (score 0):

you can go for [LoginToboggan module](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) .

```
 The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system
 in an external module.



    Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.

    Allow users to login immediately.

    Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.

    Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.

    Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.

    Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.

    Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.

    Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
```